# Remove lines of text inside parentheses

Tags: python, bash, parentheses

I have a list of links that end with numbers that is followed by text in parentheses that look something like this:

```
xxxx://12345678 (TEXT HERE) 
xxxx://98765432 (MORE TEXT HERE)
xxxx://84578452 (ALSO (SOMETIMES TEXT LIKE THIS))
```

I only want the links but not the parentheses or anything inside of it. Especially when I get to having a double set of parentheses.

I would like to use bash or python (or something else), but I have no clue where to start.

Comment: Have a look at [regexr](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: This should be fairly straight forward to implement... how about adding some lines of code that show where you actually got stuck?

Comment: I suggest to take a look at `sed` or `awk` or `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

something like this? (python)

```py
txt = ["xxxx://12345678 (TEXT HERE)", 
       "xxxx://3345 (TEXT (HERE))"]

def getlink(s):
    # and return everything until the left-parantheses and strip spaces
    return s[:s.index("(")].strip()

links = list(map(getlink, txt))

>>> ['xxxx://12345678', 'xxxx://3345']
```

Comment: I really should have prefaced this with, I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing.

3 things.

1) What do I do with the above? Do I paste it into a textedit file and save it as something specific?

2) How do I customize it to work a specific set of text, or a file?

3) Can I have new lines instead of being separated by comma?

I know zero coding. sorry!

Comment: well, if you have absolutely no idea on how to get python running you definitely should have mentioned it :-D to get the above running you would have to install a working python environment ( something like this: https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html ) and then run the code in a python-shell... you'll most probably find a lot of tutorials that help you get started.

Comment: ... however, if extracting the links is the only thing you plan on doing, then some of the UNIX tools mentioned in the comments above could be more straight-forward to implement...